# Whats the corresponding postman configuration request for this curl request?

Tags: curl, postman

```
  $ curl -XPOST -k foo:foosecret@localhost:9000/hascode/oauth/token \
   -d grant_type=password -d client_id=foo -d client_secret=abc123 \
   -d redirect_uri=http://www.hascode.com -d username=bar -d password=barsecret
```

**I want to know how to make this request on postman**